# MATLAB - Search for sound pattern in a recording

Tags: matlab, audio, filter

With MATLAB I have created a WAV file containing a pure tone of 1KHz for 50ms. This tone I play simultaneously on two speakers, 2m apart from each other. Directly in front of one of the speakers, a microphone is placed, thus 2m far from the other speaker.

The microphone thus records the 1KHz tone, with a delay of about 6ms (speed of sound ±343m/s, 2m apart)

Using the recorded sound and the original sound, I would like to calculate the actual time delay between the speakers

```
% Create pure tone: 1000Hz, 150ms
Fs      = 48828.125;
Freq    = 1000; %Hz
duration= 50; %ms
N       = round( duration / 1000 * Fs );
Fn      = Fs/2;
sig     = cumsum( ones( 1, N ) ) - 1;
sig     = sig / Fs;
snd     = sin( 2 * pi * Freq * sig);

% Possible recording: Time delay of 6ms
timedly = round( 6 / 1000 * Fs ); % 6ms time delay between speakers
rec     = [snd zeros(timedly,1)'] + [zeros(timedly,1)' snd] * 0.75; % second speaker will be recorded softer
rec     = rec + randn( 1, length(rec) ) * 0.2; % Add some noise
plot( rec )
```

I was thinking about creating a filter, based upon the original sound file and apply this to the recorded sound. Does that make sense, or should I search the solution in another direction?

Comment: Do you need to use a 50-ms tone? If you use a pulsed signal you will have much more time resolution, of the order of the pulse width

Comment: Why not just use a very short pulse (as suggested by @LuisMendo) and just do a peak detection?

Comment: Peak detection should be preceded by a filter matched to your signal, in order to increase signal-to-noise ratio. And if you use a very short pulse you gain resolution but loose signal energy. That's why I suggested a _sequence_ of short pulses. You could use a pseudorandom sequence, or a Barker sequence, and then apply a correlator that acts as a matched filter

Comment: The actual setup is slightly different from above: A unilateral conductive hearing loss test subject is fitted with a bone conductive device (speaker 2) on the skull, whereas speaker 1 is in the free field -70 to +70 degrees azimuth 2m from the test subject. A healthy normal hearing test subject must be able to detect the location of the original sound with certain degrees accuracy. I shall create a pseudo random sequence and test if source localisation is possible with it. Else I have to stick with a pure tone or narrow band sound. I'll report back.